# Replace $ with £ using cat Command

Tags: solaris, cat, replace

I have file test_output_archive.svd with some Dollar signs (`$`).
I have generated a shell script Replace_dollar_pound.sh with cat command to replace dollar symbol with Pound (`£`)
script is working on Solaris 10, Dollar getting replaced as expected.
In Solaris 11, but the dollar is not getting replaced, not throwing any errors

Content of test_output_archive.svd :
**Line Rental $9 
OOB Only for $10**

Replace Dollar symbol with Pound at step1, Remove junk charactes at step 2, Remove temp file at step3, Rename at step4**

Content of Replace_dollar_pound.sh :
**cat test_output_archive.svd | tr "\044" "\243" > temp_archive.svd
cat temp_archive.svd | tr -d "\302" > test_output_archive2.svd
rm temp_archive.svd
mv test_output_archive2.svd test_output_archive.svd**

Any Modifications to be done as OS is updated to Solaris 11 ??

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! When posting questions, please make sure to post the command that is giving you errors and the exact error message received.

Comment: Which sed is being used — `/usr/ucb/sed`, `/usr/bin/sed` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/sed`? If you don't know, edit your question to add the output of `echo "$PATH"`. What are your locale settings (output of `locale`)? What encoding do you want the resulting file to be in?

Comment: Can you post (include in your question) the output of `LC_ALL=C sed -n l < del.sh`? And of `locale charmap`? Two possibilities I'm thinking of: there's a hidden CR character at the end of the line, or you're entering £ as its latin1 representation (0xA3) instead of its UTF8 representation (0xC2 0xA3) in a UTF8 locale.

Answer (score 4):

The `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions, it means "the end of the record" (record==line in most cases). So, you need to escape it. Try this:

```
sed 's/\$/£/g' file > outfile
```

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but _not_ escaping `$` doesn't result in a "command garbled error" (whatever that is). +1 anyway, as it answers the question as well as it can.

Comment: @Sparhawk indeed, it's a valid command, it just means something else.

Comment: batch@BATCH:[~/output]$ ./del.sh sed: command garbled: s/\$/£/g

Comment: @sirajuddinmohammed 1) we have no idea what's in `del.sh` 2) Please don't add this kind of thing in the comments. Edit your question where you can [format](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) it correctly.

Comment: Contents of del.sh  :
#!/bin/sh 
#!/bin/expect
#!/bin/bash

sed 's/\$/£/g' Dollar.txt

Comment: OK, @sirajuddinmohammed this is the third time I ask you to **please not post extra information as a comment but to edit your original question instead**. Preferably, also show us an example of your input file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to replace every occurrence of a string as described [here](http://linuxtechie.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/using-sed-to-replace-words-in-a-file/):

```
sed -i 's/\£/\$/g' FILENAME
```

The `-i` option tells `sed` to operate on a file, `s` is the operator for replacing strings, `\£` is the string you need to replace, `\$` is the string that replaces each `$` character (`\` escapes the signs as they are special characters) and `g` means replace every instances.

**EDIT:** the `-i` option doesn't work on Solaris, you should use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576380/sed-i-what-the-same-option-in-solaris) workaround.

Comment: `£` is not a special character. Also, the OP wants it the other way around.

Comment: Anyway, `£` needs to be escaped at least on my version of `sed`. Sorry, but where did the OP say that escaping is not a way to go for him?

Comment: Really? What version of sed is that? `£` has no meaning in any regular expression language. The OP said no such thing (which is why I posted pretty much the same answer as you did :), I meant that he wants to replace `$` with `£` and not `£` with `$`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood something. I use `sed 4.2.1` on Debian Wheezy. And it's very strange as it only produces an error (`sed: -e expression #1, chsed: -e expression char 8: unterminated s' command`) on certain files.

Comment: And escaping the £ solves that? That's _very_ strange. I'd love to see an example of such a file. If you have the time/inclination, come into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) and show me.

Comment: batch@BATCH:[~/output]$ ./del.sh sed: illegal option -- i batch@TBATCH:[~/output]$ ./del.sh sed: command garbled: s/\£/\$/g

Comment: @sirajuddinmohammed Please edit your question to add extra info, it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: @terdon, yes, it works like a charm when escaping £. Unfortunately I can't log in to chat due to some 404 error, maybe some other time.

Comment: `-i` is Linux-specific, but this question assumes Solaris. @terdon For £ requiring a backslash, I suspect a locale issue: that you're typing the `£` character in some encoding and the resulting byte value is invalid in the encoding declared to sed. Is the `LC_CTYPE` setting returned by `locale` correct?

Comment: The locale is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, but this is not a major issue, I will open a new question for it if I experience further problems. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @Gilles, you are right about the `-i` option, I forgot about that. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the special character ($) in the sed command.

```
$ cat test.txt
£ pound £
$ dollar $
£ pound £
$ dollar $

$ sed 's/\$/£/g' test.txt
£ pound £
£ dollar £
£ pound £
£ dollar £
```

Or alternatively

```
$ sed 's/[$]/£/g' test.txt
£ pound £
£ dollar £
£ pound £
£ dollar £
```

Comment: sed: command garbled: s/\$/£/g

Comment: try using "[$]"

Comment: sed: command garbled: s/"[$]"/£/g
sed: command garbled: s/[$]/£/g
Please provide a way to display £ symbol. able to replace with some string. unable to replace with £ symbol.